# Synchronizing Threads from different objects -{EDITED}

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

JAVA - Synchronizing Threads from different objects. Refer to below example; if its one object it works fine; but if i use 2 it does not work as expected; In my use case I have say 20 objects which a different string value, and all run at the same time; the synch block are not getting respected

```
public class temp {
    synchronized void printTable(int n){//method not synchronized
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.println(n*i);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(400);
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        }

    }
}
class MyThread1 extends Thread{
    temp t;
    MyThread1(temp t){
        this.t=t;
    }
    public void run(){
        t.printTable(5);
    }

}
class MyThread2 extends Thread{
    temp t;
    MyThread2(temp t){
        this.t=t;
    }
    public void run(){
        t.printTable(100);
    }
}
class TestSynchronization1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        temp obj = new temp();//only one object
        temp obj2 = new temp();
        MyThread1 t1=new MyThread1(obj);
        MyThread2 t2=new MyThread2(obj2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:
5
100
200
10
15
300
400
20
25
500

But if I use a single instance of temp

```
class TestSynchronization1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        temp obj = new temp();//only one object
        //temp obj2 = new temp();
        MyThread1 t1=new MyThread1(obj);
        MyThread2 t2=new MyThread2(obj);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:
5
10
15
20
25
100
200
300
400
500

Comment: Please explain what behaviour you are seeing, and what behaviour you expect. What synchronised blocks do you mean, there are none in your code.

Comment: @tgdavies - I have a bunch of objects that need to run simultaneously; but when i do this in some important areas (shared methods), I see some race conditions occurring; for now I have added a delay of 700ms between runing each object to mitigate the issue

Comment: Without a description of the problem, and without the code where the problem occurs, there is no advice we can give.

Comment: Your example doesn't share any state between the threads, as each thread has its own instance of temp.

Comment: I have added the code in the description now

Comment: Output from above code:
100
5
10
200
300
15
20
400
25
500

Comment: Output when only one obj is used:
class TestSynchronization1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        temp obj = new temp();//only one object
        //temp obj2 = new temp();
        MyThread1 t1=new MyThread1(obj);
        MyThread2 t2=new MyThread2(obj);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

O/P:
5
10
15
20
25
100
200
300
400
500

Comment: The code you have above uses two instances of `temp`. Please show your actual code. You are going to have to show the code for printTable too.

Comment: And don't put your code in comments.

Comment: I have added the necessary items in the Description

Comment: That behaviour is expected. Entry to a synchronised instance method takes a lock on the instance that method is being called on.

Comment: @tgdavies Is there a way to sync threads from various objects???
I am looking for this output from the code mentioned in the desc - Output: 5 10 15 20 25 100 200 300 400 500; from the example that has 2 objects of temp

Comment: Do you really need to use threads? Why not just call the printTable methods one after the other?

Comment: But a synchronised block can use any object: `synchronized (foo) { ... }` takes a lock on the object referenced by `foo`, so you can synchronise on whatever object you wish. A synchronised member function is equivalent to synchronising on `this`.